# Constant Moment Generating Function and degenerate Random variable .

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, moment-generating-functions

Let $\{X_n\}$ be such that $X_n$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\lambda /n$ , then as known $X_n$ will converge in distribution to $Y$ which has a Poisson distribution with parameters $\lambda=n.p$ .

Now if we define a sequence $\{Z_n\}$ by $Z_n =g(X_n,n)=X_n/n$ then the Moment generating function of $Z_n$ will be $$M_{Z_n}(t)=(1+(\lambda/n)(exp(t/n)-1))^n$$ then as $n \rightarrow \infty$ , $M_{Z_n}(t) \rightarrow 1 $

My question is , is that mean that $P(z=1)=1$ or $P(z=0)=1$ ?

Comment: Think of it without mgf. You take a Poisson and divide it by $n\to\infty$. What does it tend to?

Comment: @A.S.Degenerate Random variable  zero , so what does 1 mean , the number  to which the moment generating function approaches ?

Comment: It means that $e^{0\cdot t}=1$.

Comment: @A.S. So it means the value of function at $x=0$ not at $t=0$ , thanks a lot :) .

Comment: It's a value at $X=0$ for all values of $t$.